# Split Total Integer into two fields with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created 3 input type numbers and it is basically an addition of two values to get the total. My challenge is that when i input a value into the field for Total Sum; i want it split into the two input fields automatically.
e.g #1: **9** #2: **3** #Total: 12
and if the Total is edited by the user and maybe a value of 100 is place there i should have #1: **15** #2: **5** #Total: 20

Note: Number 1 and Number 2 can be edited to give total sum only but when sum is edited it should split into Number 1 and Number 2.

## HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="addvalue">

<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<p>Number 1: <input type="number" ng-change="update()" ng-model="firstNumber"></p>
<p>Number 2: <input type="number" ng-change="update()" ng-model="secondNumber"></p>
<p>Total Sum: <input type="number" ng-change="update()" ng-model="total">{{total}}</p>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.$watch('one + two + three', function(value) {
$scope.total = value;
});
$scope.change = function() {
  if (istotal) {
    $scope.firstNumber = $scope.total / 2;
    $scope.secondNumber = $scope.total / 4;
  } else {
    $scope.total = $scope.firstNumber + $scope.secondNumber;
  }
}

});
```

Comment: If you put a value of 100, it should be 75 and 25 right?

Comment: Also, can you edit number 1 and number 2 themselves? E.g. I enter 20, it shows 15 and 5. If I type 18 into number 1 should it update number 2 to 6 and total to 24? Or should only an edit of total trigger updates of the other fields?

Comment: yes @ jeff carey for first question. Number 1 and Number 2 can be edited to give sum only. but when sum is edited it should split into Number 1 and Number 2.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing boolean parameter in update().
In case of number 1 and number 2 keep it as `ng-change = "update(false)"`.
and for total keep it as `ng-change = "update(true)"`.
In controller.

```
$scope.update(isTotal) {
    if(istotal) { 
        $scope.firstNumber = 3 * $scope.total / 4;
        $scope.secondNumber = 1 * $scope.total / 4;
    } else {
        $scope.total = $scope.firstNumber + $scope.secondNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not necessary to return the values in the if statement?

Comment: No. return is not required, as Angular uses two way binding, values will be updated automatically.